# Remove white spaces line breaks from the extracted text Python scraping

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am facing an issue regarding extracting text from the website page. I am using the `XPath` selector and `Scrapy` for this.

The page contains the markup like this:

```
<div class="snippet-content">
    <h2>First Child</h2>
    <p>Hello</p>
    This is large text ..........
</div>
```

I basically need the text after the 2 immediate children. The selector which I am using is this:

```
text = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "snippet-content")]/text()[last()]').get()
```

The text is extracted correctly but it contains `white spaces`, `NBPS`, and new line break `\r\n` characters.

**For example:**

Extracting text is like this:

```
"         \r\nRemarks byNBPS Deputy Prime Minister andNBPS Coordinating Minister for Economic Policies Heng Swee Keat at the Opening of the Bilingualism Carnival on 8 April 2023.                                "
```

Is there a way to get sanitized and clean text without all trailing `whitespaces`, `linebreaks` characters, and NBPS characters?

Comment: May be surround the xpath expression with [normalize-space()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space)

Comment: why can't you just use the python `.strip()` method on the string?

Comment: @Alexander I ca use this but I have to remove line breaks and other special characters so I was looking for the native xpath function.

Comment: @LMC Can you write an answer based on your comment? I will accept that answer.

Comment: @VenNilson  `str.strip()` removes all whitespace characters by default including line breaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the xpath function `normalize-space`, but this does more than simply removing whitespace from the beginning and end of a string.  If the string also contains runs of spaces or other whitespace characters it would also reduce them down to a single whitespace regardless of where they are located in the string.

Alternatively you can use the python `str.strip` method which by default(without setting a parameter) only removes whitespace characters from the beginning and end of a string.

Examples:

```py
text = response.xpath('normalize-space(//div[contains(@class, "snippet-content")]/text()[last()])').get()
```

```
text = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "snippet-content")]/text()[last()]').get().strip()
```